# How to replace "N/A" data with "0" in sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace all the the occurrences of `N/A` from my file with 0.

I tried `sed 's/N/A/0/' 1.csv`, but it doesn't works due to the `/` characters.

Can someone help me to fix the command?

Comment: In addition to the answer given (which I prefer), you can also escape the slash: `sed 's/N\/A/0/' 1.csv`. With just a little Googling, this information is easy to find. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different sed delimiter.

```
sed 's~N/A~0~g' file
```

Comment: or escape the forward slash. `sed 's/N\/A/0/' 1.csv`

Answer (score 0):

if not only number in CSV

```
sed 's/.*/,&,/;s#,N/A,#,0,/g;s/,\(.*\),/\1/' YourFile.csv
```

to avoid changing string that contain the sequence like `ON/AVAILABLE`